# Fatal DB query syntax error on rules search - Civi 5.0.0 and recent Civirules

Tags: error, civirules, sql

I have 7 rules set up to help automate membership management.  All are tagged with the same tag and all but one are active.  WHen I search by tag or for all rules I get the correct result, but when I search by the tag AND all rules I get a DB query syntax fatal error. This is from the log:

[db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix=""

info="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(crr.id)) AS total 
      FROM civirule_rule crr
LEFT JOIN civirule_trigger crtrigger ON crr.trigger_id = crtrigger.id
LEFT JOIN civirule_rule_tag crtag ON crr.id = crtag.rule_id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact contact ON crr.created_user_id = contact.id **WHERE  AND** (crtag.rule_tag_id = 1)

[nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND (crtag.rule_tag_id = 1)' at line 5]"]

I suppose that some condition is expected between **WHERE  AND** that I emphasized in bold.   This same error happens on Civirules 1.23 and 2.1.  The upgrade also updated the database, but I tested on a separate, older system that had not been upgraded.

Could this be due to some database corruption or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know without checking on your site. I have recently tested 2.1 on an existing site and it worked there. You might want to check if the civirule_condition table is still populated? It might be that it got accidently cleaned out.

If that is the case, you will have to take note of what your conditions/actions where, run the sql scripts **insertCiviRulesConditions** and **insertCiviRuleActions** from the sql folder of the extension to re-create them. And then you have to rebuild your rules in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the response.   Civirule_condition is populated but I see that civirule_rule_action and civirule_rule_condition are empty. The site was recently moved from development domain to the live domain, and the database imported and domain names adjusted.

Comment: But the same problem is occurring on the older development site with same Civi version and older civirules.  I will try retesting the state transitions to make sure its all working.

Comment: As said, I have not experienced your problem nor do we have issues reported on the CiviRules repo that mention this problem. It might indeed be caused by civirule_rule_action and civirule_rule_condition being empty. No idea what caused that on the older development site, but that smells like database corruption.

Comment: So somehow all the rule conditions and actions were deleted in the move or upgrade of the extension.  I recreated all of these and they look ok in the tables, but so far the database error is still present.  Is this a change that requires clearing the cache?

Comment: yes that might work. Give it a try?